# EXTRACT function SQLite support?

Tags: sqlite

In sqlite if I input such a query:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM '2018-07-22')
```

I got a error. I'd like to confirm that if Sqlite support such function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite does not support `EXTRACT()` function.
Instead there is [`strftime()`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html):

```
SELECT strftime('%Y', '2018-07-22')
```